# Deserialize nested json string which contains special characters into an object

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have user sending messages that might contain any special characters. I get that data as json string. I am trying to deserialize the string into an object and then pass it to my webapi.

But, I am not able to successfully deserialize the data. I have created a simple c# console app to test this function.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {            
        Console.WriteLine("Enter input:"); 
        string data = Console.ReadLine(); 

        // One of the SO article says,
        // If the JSON is created using a JSON serializer, then all the
        // special characters will be escaped properly
        var sData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);     

        MappedData mappedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MappedData>(dData.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine(mappedData.PostData); //these need to be posted to webapi
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public class MappedData
{
    [JsonProperty("PostData")]
    public string PostData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MessageQueueInformation")]
    public string MessageQueueInformation { get; set; }
}
```

article referred: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706943/json-net-deserialize-string-which-contains-special-characters)

Test data that works (no special chars):
`{ "MessageQueueInformation": '{"EntityId":"13","Action":"Add"}', "PostData": '{"listMessage":[{"message":"Successful case 1"}]}'}`

This fails with error: `Bad JSON escape sequence: \,.`

`{ "MessageQueueInformation": '{"EntityId":"13","Action":"Add"}', "PostData": '{"listMessage":[{"message":"Unsuccessful case- aaa /, \, ^, &amp;, %, #'/"\\\,''!~"}]}'}`

Comment: When you stringify your object, have you tried using `WebUtility.HtmlEncode(yourJsonString)`? This does good at escaping characters, also

Comment: @GeoffJames: HtmlEncode will escape characters for HTML, not for JSON.

Comment: Thanks @StriplingWarrior - I just picked up on some of the characters in the string, and thought it might have helped :)

Comment: If the user is sending **valid** JSON everything will be alright. Point him to http://json.org and one of the online JSON validators

Comment: @SirRufo Your test case tests nothing..... Only console input can be serialized or not.

Comment: @Eser Which test case? I did not post any test case

Comment: `var sData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);     

        MappedData mappedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MappedData>(dData.ToString());`  What is your input so that you expect it to be  deserialized to `MappedData`

Comment: BTW: `I have created a simple c# console app to test this function.` What does this mean? Not a test case?

Comment: @Eser, it's me and not SirRufo. I have created it just to see how can i deserialize the input string. The input string are at the bottom of the post. Those strings are being passed by another program.

Comment: @SriReddy Don't create your json manually. You can, for ex, create an **anonymous** object like `new {MessageQueueInformation=new{EntityId=13}}` etc and serialize it....

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but your user needs to change the messages he sends to actually be JSON. JSON input needs to be encoded properly.

- If you want `\` to appear in a string, then in a JSON string it will appear as `\\`.
- If you want `"` to appear in a string, then it should appear as `\"`.
- If you want `'` to appear in a string, then it should appear as `\'`.

`{ "MessageQueueInformation": '{"EntityId":"13","Action":"Add"}', "PostData": '{"listMessage":[{"message":"Unsuccessful case- aaa /, \\, ^, &amp;, %, #'/\"\\\\\\,\'\'!~"}]}'}`

Comment: actually user enter this in an external webpage and we get the data via an external api which i have no control. So, I guess I need to replace the special characters with proper encoded values before i pass it to the deserializer? I thought instead of Replace() there is a better way.

Comment: @SriReddy: Blindly replacing values is not a valid solution, because if they're sending bad JSON then there will be ambiguous cases where you can't know what the intent was. What exactly is the user entering? The `message`? The `PostData`? Or the whole JSON value that we're seeing here? Whatever constructs this JSON needs to be responsible for making it valid. If the external webpage is taking `message` as user input and constructing this JSON, then they should be using `JSON.stringify()` on a javascript object rather than hacking together strings this way.